# Как из winapi кликнуть на всплывающие окно чужого приложения?

Tags: c#, winapi, telegram

Всем привет, допустим хочу создать опрос у себя в чате Телеграма через winapi и клики по координатам.

[image: Создать опрос]

Все отлично кликается на эти 3 точки, когда я делаю это вручную, мышка остается в положении этих 3 точек, а потом переходит плавно в меню.
А вот когда через winapi Делаю тоже самое, то фокус не остается на 3 точках и сразу же уходит, из-за чего невозможно кликнуть по "Создать опрос" т.к. меню закрывается за миллисекунду.

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, IntPtr.Zero, MakeLParam(100, 100));
CommonCode.SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)MK_LBUTTON, MakeLParam(100, 100));
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, MakeLParam(100, 100));
```

Помогите, как решить?

Comment: Покажите ваш код, как можно о чем то судить без кода,

Comment: Есть "мышиный фокус", читайте  `SetCature`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426327/mouse-movement-capture

Comment: @nick_n_a Честно говоря не совсем понятно, как и где использовать этот setcapture. Пытался написать так SendMessage(hwnd, SetCapture, IntPtr.Zero, MakeLParam(100, 100)); Но вылетают ошибки, т.к. 2 аргумент должен быть Uint, а setcapture IntPtr

Comment: Нет, есть WinApi функция `SetCapture` которая сообщает окну, что оно будет вести фокус ввода мыши. В с++ в случае внешнего управления советуют mouse_event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630339/c-to-c-sharp-mouse-event Скорее всего он вам и поможет, если нет, то прийдется ещё и SetCapture сделать. Ещё может быть загвоздка с координатами мыши.

Comment: @nick_n_a Видимо меня не правильно поняли, клики у меня проходят хорошо, все дело во всплывающем окне, я хз как его оставить в том же положении, т.к. следующие комманды просто "стирают" предыдущие, попробуй сайте, если не трудно поймете о чем я

Comment: Я понял, окно убегает. Попробуйте окно активировать функцией `SetActiveWindow`, попробуйте установите фокус `SetCapture`, или оба одновременно. Окно проверяет фокус, и при его отсутствии пропадает.

Comment: Что б было как-то лучше... Можно попробовать "влоб" перебрать комманды акселераторов через WM_COMMAND, можно пошерстить ресурсы (ResourseHacker, exescope), если ID в меню телеграма назначено - то его можно напрямую активировать через WM_COMMAND, и не мучать визуалку.

Comment: @nick_n_a В телеграме все QT. Убегает не окно, а именно элемент (как мне кажется)

Answer (score 0):

В общем решил проблему через SetCursorPos(хотелось бы вообще без использования мышки). Получается ставлю координаты относительно самого экрана, и нужно всегда держать телеграм в позиции 0.0.